# Using Swift how can i add an horizontal banner to an image similar to Tidal

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I need assistance with placing a banner on the top right corner of a UIImage within my UI. Can someone guide me on how to achieve this?

I am trying to create a ribbon-shaped UIView that looks like the image below using iOS. I aim to put this ribbon custom view in each music image cell, which has its own view.

[Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUHJA.png)